# App_name as system.data.sqlclient

Tags: sql-server, system.data.sqlclient

I am getting system.data.sqlclient as app_name in my database through my dot net application. Which application is connecting through system.data.sqlclient application name.

Comment: You can define the "App_Name" in the connection string - if you don't specify anything, I believe the name of the provider (here `System.Data.SqlClient`) is used by default

Comment: I have defined app_name , instead I am getting this in few rows. Is it due to sql-injection or cross site scripting.

Comment: Then please **show us** the connection string you're using!

Comment: The proper SqlClient [connection string keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) is `Application Name=`

Comment: This relate article may help.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/use-application-name-sql-server/